# XSD: restrict attribute to xs:float or ""

Tags: xsd

I'm trying to define an element type in XSD, for which i want an optional attribute, which if present can either contain a float, or be empty (but still present).

i.e:

```
<xs:element name="MyElement">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="optionalFloatAttribute" type="xs:float" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Needs "fixing" to allow all of the following xml:-

```
<MyElement/>
 or
 <MyElement optionalFloatAttribute=""/>
 or
 <MyElement optionalFloatAttribute="3.14159"/>
```

The only way I can see of doing this is to change type to `xs:string`, and use `xs:restriction` with a regular expression. But this doesn't seem very ideal to me. Is there a better way?

And I *have* to be able to support these variations of the xml - the program and existing xml is legacy, and I am trying to back-create a schema to match the myriad variations I see in what we have to regard as valid xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to handle this and use `xs:float`. Fundamentally it comes down to the fact that empty string isn't a valid number. You'd either normally expect a value of 0, or for the element to be missing altogether. There's a good explanation as the answer to the following question:

[Empty elements for primitve datatypes forbidden in XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043496/empty-elements-for-primitve-datatypes-forbidden-in-xsd)

It seems that the option of using xs:string and a regexp might be your best plan.

Answer (score 6):

You can define custom type for that by combining float and empty string:

```
<xs:element name="MyElement">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="optionalFloatAttribute" type="emptyFloat" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="emptyFloat">
    <xs:union>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
                <xs:length value="0"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base='xs:float'>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:union>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Or using regExp:

```
<xs:simpleType name="emptyFloat">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="-?\d*\.?\d*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: I assume you can do the same thing with attributes by using `complexType`s? This is an excellent answer and solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you could stand using an element rather than an attribute you could make the xs:float nillable. This way you can use the xsi:nil="true" in your instance document to indicate that the element has no value:

```
<!-- definition -->
<xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:float" nillable="true" />  

<!-- instance -->
<quantity xsi:nil="true" />
```

No equivalent for attributes though.